# Counting total number of local maxima and minima of a function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Find the total number of local maxima and local minima for the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
         (2+x)^{3}  &\text{if}\, -3 \lt x \le -1 \\
         (x)^\frac{2}{3}  &\text{if}\, -1 \lt x \lt 2 
       \end{cases}
$$

My attempt : I differentiated the function for the two different intervals and obtained the following:
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
         3\cdot(2+x)^{2}  &\text{if}\, -3 \lt x \le -1 \\
         \frac{2}{3}\cdot (x)^\frac{-1}{3}  &\text{if}\, -1 \lt x \lt 2 
       \end{cases}
$$
How do I obtain the maxima and minima points from here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: extrema occur where $f'(x) = 0$, $f'(x)$ is undefined, and/or endpoints.

Comment: @Dando18, "extrema may occur where..." In the problem given, $f'(-2)=0$ but $(-2,0)$ is not an extrema.

Comment: @BernardMassé Yeah I meant $ \text{extrema} \implies f'(x)=0,\, \dots$ not the other way around.

Comment: Just draw the graph?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to study $f'$ :

What is the sign of $f'(x), x\in ]-3 , 2 [$ ?

A local maxima/minima $x_m$ appears when :

- $f'(x_m) = 0$ or $x_m$ is a remarquable point (here $x_m \in \{-3,-1,2\}$)
- $f'$ changes sign before and after $x_m$

If the second condition is not verified, $x_m$ is an inflection point.

Comment: I think x=0 is another remarkable point here, since f'(x) becomes undefined at x=0 .

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't do the $f'$ study before posting my answer but indeed as pointed out by Dando18 if $f'$ is undefined then you should check the nature of the point.